# how to get a colon ":" after the short abbreviation in acronym

Tags: punctuation, acronyms

I was wondering how to get in my acronym list ":" (colon) after the short abbreviation, for example:

I want to get

> UV: Ultra Violet

but I keep getting

> UV Ultra Violet

without the colon.

Comment: Please give us a minimal working example. There are several ways to achieve acronyms with LaTeX (if that's what you're using), and we can't know which you're using and what commands, packages etc.

Answer (score 9):

You could redefine `\bflabel` to achieve that:

```
\renewcommand*{\bflabel}[1]{{\textbf{\textsf{#1}:}\hfill}}
```

Full Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\renewcommand*{\bflabel}[1]{{\textbf{\textsf{#1}:}\hfill}}
\begin{document}
\ac{uv}
\section*{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[UV]
\acro{uv}[UV]{Ultra Violet}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

[image: acronym example]

Comment: google brought me here and further googling brought me to the more current solution:`\bflabel` was apparently deprecated some time ago, now, the documented form `\aclabelfont` can be used (as stated in the [package documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf)